# UserControl Focus Issue - Focus() sometimes returns false

Tags: .net, user-controls

I have a user control that behaves similar to a tab control. 
The tab headers are `UserControl` instances that override `Paint` events to make them look custom.

In order to leverage the Validating events on various controls on our tab pages, when the user clicks on the tab headers, we set the Focus to the `TabHeader` user control.

I've noticed that `Control.Focus()` returns false sometimes but the documentation does not say why `Control.Focus()` will ever return false other than that the control can't receive focus.  But I don't know why.

Here's what I see:
If my `TabHeader` `UserControl` does not contain any sub-controls, and I call `myControl.Focus()` from the `MouseClick` event, focus returns true.

If my `TabHeader` `UserControl` contains a sub-control and I call `myControl.Focus()` from the `MouseClick` event, focus returns false.

If my `TabHeader` `UserControl` contains a sub-control, and I call `myControl.subControl.Focus()` from the `myControl.MouseClick` event, focus returns true.

Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 5):

Calling `Focus()` on a `UserControl` selects the first childcontrol of that UserControl. That would indeed explain your behaviour.

You can try to call `Select()` instead of `Focus()` and see if that works.

Comment: Even though this answer was several years old, this solution worked for me.  I had a user control that was enabled when a node on a tree view was clicked and depending on whether the user was adding, editing or deleting, a different control in the user control would need the focus.  Select() worked like a charm.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try "Control.ContainsFocus"? This is supposed to return true if any of the child controls have focus on it. [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.containsfocus%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Thanks,
James